# I want to get an array of variables from wordpress database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a form set up where I am retrieving all users who fit a certain criteria (shoe size between 9-15). But sometimes it could be 1 user, 5 users or 0 users depending on the criteria.

I have a get_var set up but that only returns 1 variable and it breaks my code when it returns multiple values.

```
$woShoeMemberId = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT user
    FROM data
    WHERE field=16
    AND value BETWEEN ".$_POST['woShoes']." AND ".$_POST['woShoes2']."");
```

How can I turn this into an array? Like $woShoeMemberId would contain an array of 'user' depending on the search results?

Also I then must turn those Ids into usernames which I do by

```
$woShoeMember = $wpdb->get_var(
    'SELECT login
    FROM users
    WHERE ID='.$woShoeMemberId.'');
```

Same issue, how do I turn that into an array of usernames depending on the amount of Ids I have?

Comment: From the wpdb codex. `Warning: As with all functions in this class that execute SQL queries, you must SQL escape all inputs to prevent SQL injection attacks! Check the documentation to see if the function you plan to use escapes SQL for you or leaves it un-escaped!!! `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get_var()`, use `get_results()` or `get_col()`.

The `get_var()` method will always return a single result.

The `get_results()` method will return an array with objects that contain the selected results

The `get_col()` method will return an array with the selected results.

Comment: would those return arrays? so having just $woShoeMemberId = $wpdb->get_results() that would turn my variable into an array? or do I have to initialize it as an array